# C#, Access DbContext in Method of DAL Project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core and have added DbContext class in DAL project where connection string DI are set in main project in service container.

I have introduce the Abstract class in DAL project where all Query classes expected to extend BaseQuery. I want to initialize dbContext in baseQuery but not in constructor, If I add in DbContext in BaseQuery constructor then it means extended class needs to know DbContext which I don't want it. Ideally I want extended class to just use dbContext as inherited property

### BaseQuery

```
public abstract class BaseQuery<TResult> where TResult : class
{
    protected AppDbContext appDbContext;

    private void SetDbContext(????)
    {
        this.appDbContext= dbContext;
    }

    public BaseQuery()
    {
        SetDbContext(?????);
    }

    public abstract TResult Execute();
}
```

}

### DbContext

```
 public class AppDbContext: DbContext
 { 
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {

    }

  //DbSets
  }
```

Comment: Alternative approach - don't create abstract class on this stage - use multiple query classes with duplicated code. After that when you actually see a real duplication only then you can extract it it to the base class maybe.

Comment: what you are looking for is a generic repository pattern, that way you dont need to think about extending base class every time instead a generic repo will take care of all your entities and you can call complex functions just by extending AsQueryable() method

Comment: I don't want to use repository pattern.. I just need to resolve DbContext in BaseQuery may be through property / method dependencies

Comment: Can you show how you are going to use this base query in the code?

Comment: You should look into dependecy injection. I think that would be a good alternative to what you are trying to achieve here.